# How to get groups from predecessor and successor table with SQL Server or Vertica SQL

Tags: sql, database, tree, vertica

I have the following data structure within a SQL database (ideally Vertica).

| id_predecessor | id_successor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 47 | 48 |
| 48 | 49 |
| ... | ... |

The table contains relationships between orders by that multiple orders could be connected to a group. For example there is one order group (A) with 5 orders total. The relationship is as follows:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbEC7.jpg)

And another order group (B) with a simple relationship:

1 — 2 - 3

... and I would like to get the following structure out of it:

| net_id | id | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 2 |
| A | 4 | 3 |
| A | 5 | 3 |
| B | 47 | 1 |
| B | 48 | 2 |
| B | 49 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

For each net that is connected I would like to assign a unique net id. The main problem is, that I can have multiple start nodes and also multiple end nodes in each net, so I do not have a clear starting point, to assign a net id. I do not care about the value format of the net id, it should just be a unique id for each net, to filter for specific nets.

Thank you, hope there is a easy solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with sql server. But regardless which DBMS you are using you have obfuscated the data so much that the question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make it a multi-step process.

a) Create your input table

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE indata
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
WITH
indata(id_predecessor,id_successor) AS (
          SELECT 1,3 
UNION ALL SELECT 2,3 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,4 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,5 
UNION ALL SELECT 47,48
UNION ALL SELECT 48,49
)
SELECT * FROM indata;
```

b) Create the three-node, two-edge, graphs with a recursive query.

```
-- 1. create 3-node graphs with a recursive query
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE graph
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
WITH RECURSIVE rec AS (
  SELECT
    id_predecessor
  , id_successor
  , id_successor AS id_middle
  , (id_predecessor::VARCHAR(3)||'>'||id_successor::VARCHAR(3))::VARCHAR(32) AS graph
  , 1 AS lvl
  FROM indata
  WHERE id_predecessor NOT IN (
    SELECT id_successor FROM indata
  )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.id_predecessor
  , c.id_successor
  , p.id_middle
  , (p.graph ||'>'||c.id_successor::VARCHAR(3))::VARCHAR(32) AS graph
  , p.lvl + 1 AS lvl
  FROM indata c
  JOIN rec    p ON c.id_predecessor = p.id_successor
)
SELECT
  *
FROM rec
WHERE lvl = 2
ORDER BY id_middle;

--SELECT * FROM graph;
-- out  id_predecessor | id_successor | id_middle |  graph   | lvl 
-- out ----------------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----
-- out               3 |            4 |         3 | 1>3>4    |   2
-- out               3 |            4 |         3 | 2>3>4    |   2
-- out               3 |            5 |         3 | 1>3>5    |   2
-- out               3 |            5 |         3 | 2>3>5    |   2
-- out              48 |           49 |        48 | 47>48>49 |   2
```

Then,

- get the distinct middle ID-s from the query above
- using the sort order of the middle-IDs, generate 'A' and 'B' in a lookup table
- you can use the `graph` column built here, to get one row per node in the graph, using the `EXPLODE()` function
- and join that `EXPLODE()` query back to the distinct group identifiers, applying a DISTINCT to avoid doublets.

```
WITH
ids_middle AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      id_middle
    FROM graph
)
,
groupids(id_grp,id_middle) AS (
  SELECT
    CHR(ASCII('A')-1+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id_middle))
  , id_middle
  FROM  ids_middle
  -- SELECT * FROM groupids;
  -- out  id_grp | id_middle
  -- out --------+--------
  -- out  A      |      3
  -- out  B      |     48
)
,
vertical AS (
  SELECT
    EXPLODE(
      id_middle
    , lvl
    , STRING_TO_ARRAY(graph USING PARAMETERS collection_delimiter='>')
    ) OVER(PARTITION BEST)
  FROM graph
    -- out  id_middle | lvl | position | value 
    -- out -----------+-----+----------+-------
    -- out          3 |   2 |        0 | 1
    -- out          3 |   2 |        1 | 3
    -- out          3 |   2 |        2 | 4
    -- out          3 |   2 |        0 | 2
    -- out          3 |   2 |        1 | 3
    -- out          3 |   2 |        2 | 4
    -- out          3 |   2 |        0 | 1
    -- out          3 |   2 |        1 | 3
    -- out          3 |   2 |        2 | 5
    -- out          3 |   2 |        0 | 2
    -- out          3 |   2 |        1 | 3
    -- out          3 |   2 |        2 | 5
    -- out         48 |   2 |        0 | 47
    -- out         48 |   2 |        1 | 48
    -- out         48 |   2 |        2 | 49
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  id_grp
, value        AS id
, position + 1 AS level
FROM vertical
JOIN groupids USING(id_middle)
ORDER BY id_grp;
-- out  id_grp | id | level 
-- out --------+----+-------
-- out  A      | 1  |     1
-- out  A      | 2  |     1
-- out  A      | 3  |     2
-- out  A      | 4  |     3
-- out  A      | 5  |     3
-- out  B      | 47 |     1
-- out  B      | 48 |     2
-- out  B      | 49 |     3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and great description. It did work like a charm.